# rsync cannot find file when executed from within Popen in python

Tags: python, ssh, rsync

I am attempting to write a function which will take two arguments - `source` and `output` and make a call to rsync in order to copy the source file to the output folder. Here is the meat of that function:

```
# Run rsync
try:
    command = ['/usr/bin/rsync', "-avz", "-e", '"ssh -i rsync-key"', source, dest]
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdo, stde = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception("Failed to run rsync command {} with return code of {}. {}".format(' '.join(command), p.returncode, stde))
    else:
        logging.info("Done running rsync command {} with return code of {}. {}".format(' '.join(command), p.returncode, stdo))
except Exception as ex:
    raise Exception("Failed to run rsync command {}. {}".format(' '.join(command), ex))
```

`rsync-key` is a private ssh key (with permissions 700) in the same directory as the python script and I have the public key inside the `authorized_keys` file on my server (to test my script I am attempting to copy a file from the same server).

I am testing the script with source file `USERNAME@localhost:/home/USERNAME/.vimrc` and output folder `tmp/`. Both of these locations exist.

If I run it with a local path (instead of the `USERNAME@localhost:...`) it also runs just fine.

When I run this python program I am getting the following output

```
CRITICAL $(asctime)-15s Error with rsync: Failed to run rsync command /usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "ssh -i rsync-key" USERNAME@localhost:/home/USERNAME/.vimrc tmp/. 
Failed to run rsync command /usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "ssh -i rsync-key" USERNAME@localhost:/home/USERNAME/.vimrc tmp/ with return code of 14. rsync: 
Failed to exec ssh -i rsync-key: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [receiver=3.0.4]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(641) [receiver=3.0.4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch.py", line 95, in main
    rsync(args.source_file, args.output_dir)
  File "fetch.py", line 57, in rsync
    raise Exception("Failed to run rsync command {}. {}".format(' '.join(command), ex))
```

However, if I run the same command `/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "ssh -i rsync-key" USERNAME@localhost:/home/USERNAME/.vimrc tmp/` in the normal shell it runs without a hitch. Any idea why python does not seem to be able to find my `rsync-key` file?

I look forward to any responses!

Comment: Don't use quotes around your `ssh` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some extra quotes in there. Remove one set of quotes around the `ssh` command in this line as follows:

```
command = ['/usr/bin/rsync', "-avz", "-e", "ssh -i rsync-key", source, dest]
```

The reason is that by using a `command` that is a list, you're not running through the shell so the usual shell parsing rules do not apply. Your list directly contains each argument that is passed to the subprocess, and arguments can contain spaces.